# Regular expression to match string from url

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing

I want to match shop name from a url .Please see the example below. Its for url redirection in a word press application.

See the examples given below

```
http://example.com/outlets/19-awok?page=2
http://example.com/outlets/19-awok
http://example.com/outlets/159-awok?page=3
```

In all cases i need to get only **awok** from the url .It will be the text coming after '-' and before query string .

I tried below and its not working

```
/outlets/(\d+)-(.*)? => /shop/$2
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use: `/outlets/\d+-([^?]+)`

Comment: Thanks . But its giving 'shop/awok/?page=12' . Its not removing the querystring part :(

Comment: That is because of your plugin. Try this in target URI: `/outlets/\d+-([^?]+)?` (with a trailing `?`)

Comment: thank you please post it as answer . i will make it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/outlets/\d+-([^?]+)?
```

Trailing `?` is used to strip previous query string.